# Avoid space between JToolBar and JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager

I was creating a `JFrame` example. In this process first I taken frame then add `JMenuBar` then I add `JToolbar` and then I add `JTextPane`.  In menu bar I add `File Menu` then I add create `MenuItem` to file menu. When I click on create menu item open an internal frame as plain document.  But, huge space is displayed between toolbar and tabbed pane.  How to avoid that space?

Here is code:

```
public class CreateDoc extends javax.swing.JFrame {
JScrollPane scrollPane;
JTextPane textPane;
int i=0;
public CreateDoc() {
    initComponents();
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    createToolBar = new javax.swing.JToolBar();
    Help = new javax.swing.JButton();
    tabbedPane = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
    createMenuBar = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    createMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    create = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    createToolBar.setRollover(true);

    Help.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/about.png"))); // NOI18N
    Help.setToolTipText(create.getText());
    Help.setFocusable(false);
    Help.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    Help.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    createToolBar.add(Help);

    createMenu.setText("File");

    create.setText("Create");
    create.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            createActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    createMenu.add(create);

    createMenuBar.add(createMenu);

    setJMenuBar(createMenuBar);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(createToolBar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 405, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(tabbedPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 405, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(createToolBar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 254, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(0, 22, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(tabbedPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 257, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void createActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    final JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("");
    i++;
    internalFrame.setName("Document"+i);
    internalFrame.setClosable(true);
    internalFrame.setAutoscrolls(true);
    textPane=new JTextPane();
    textPane.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Miriam Fixed", 0, 14));
    scrollPane=new JScrollPane(textPane);
        internalFrame.add(scrollPane);
        tabbedPane.add(internalFrame);
        internalFrame.setSize(internalFrame.getMaximumSize());
        internalFrame.pack();
        internalFrame.setVisible(true);
}                                      

public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CreateDoc.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CreateDoc.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CreateDoc.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CreateDoc.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new CreateDoc().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton Help;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem create;
private javax.swing.JMenu createMenu;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar createMenuBar;
private javax.swing.JToolBar createToolBar;
private javax.swing.JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the line `.addGap(0, 22, Short.MAX_VALUE)` with `.addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)`. Does this solve your problem?

EDIT:
Comment taken into consideration. I have changed the layout used a bit so that it works correctly.

```
private void initComponents() {

    createToolBar = new javax.swing.JToolBar();
    Help = new javax.swing.JButton();
    tabbedPane = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
    createMenuBar = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    createMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    create = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    createToolBar.setRollover(true);
// Commented for testing only - pls uncomment
//      Help.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(
//              "/about.png"))); // NOI18N
        Help.setToolTipText(create.getText());
        Help.setFocusable(false);
        Help.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        Help.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    createToolBar.add(Help);

    createMenu.setText("File");

    create.setText("Create");
    create.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            createActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    createMenu.add(create);

    createMenuBar.add(createMenu);

    setJMenuBar(createMenuBar);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(
            getContentPane());
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(createToolBar, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 405, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(tabbedPane, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 415, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(createToolBar, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(2)
                .addComponent(tabbedPane, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 268, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);

    pack();
}
```

Comment: Thank you,When run the program,The result window will be small not maximize.when maximize the window then click on create menuitem then the space is displayed between toolbar and tabbedpane.I had tried the above solutions but not working.Please check it once

Comment: I would also recomment using Eclipse with Google Web Tool Kit and Window Builder. Its much better (cleaner) than Netbeans for creating GUI in Swing.

Answer (score 0):

I have executed your code and found the solution that you are looking for.
In your code:

```
layout.setVerticalGroup(
...
```

in the second `addGroup` option just change the value 22 in code `addGap(0, 22, Short.MAX_VALUE)`.
Reduce the value 22 will help you to reduce the gap between your tabbed pane and the menu bar.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you,When run the program,The result window will be small not maximize.when maximize the window then click on create menuitem then the space is displayed between toolbar and tabbedpane.I had tried the above solutions but not working.Please check it once

Answer (score 0):

You should not add gap to the tabpane in the setVerticalGroup(),

Modified code:

```
layout.setVerticalGroup(layout
                .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(
                        layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(createToolBar,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(0, 254, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(
                        layout.createParallelGroup(
                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addGroup(
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,
                                        layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE) // Do not add gap here or set as minimum**
                                                .addComponent(
                                                        tabbedPane,
                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                        257,
                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))));

        pack();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Modify the group layout like below:

```
javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(tabbedPane, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 424, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(createToolBar, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 424, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(createToolBar, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 16, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(tabbedPane, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 209, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
```